# Multiple records per page directory in a mail merge

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I'm working on a mail merge document in Word that's getting the data from an Excel file.

[image: Picture of the Excel file format]

I will only be using the fields: `Codigo`, `Nombre`, `Objetivos Nuevos`, `Duracion` and `Area`. `Area` is the find I'll be using to create the new document. I want the Word document to look like:

[image: How I want the word document to look]

breaking to a new page for every new `Area`. I have found this code:

```
    { If { MERGESEQ } = "1" "{ MERGEFIELD CITY }¶
" ""}{ SET Place1 { MERGEFIELD CITY }}¶
{ If { Place2 } <> { Place1 }"¶
----------------------------Page Break--------------------------------
{ MERGEFIELD CITY }¶
¶
{ MERGEFIELD EMPLOYEE } { MERGEFIELD SALES }" "{ MERGEFIELD EMPLOYEE } { MERGEFIELD SALES }" }{ SET Place2 { MERGEFIELD CITY }}¶
```

but I can't get it to work for my specific case.

Can someone tell me how I need to write this code so that it works for my specific case?

Comment: What happens with the "Page Break" when you run the merge?

Comment: I get the same result as with out the code but it shows me the text from the code in the page.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referencing the Knowledge Base article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211303

You need to read this through very carefully in order to understand how it all works. In brief, the "list header" is the key (City, in the example; Area, in your case). Very important is that the data is sorted so that all entries for a particular key are consecutive! This is not the case in the Excel information you show us, so you need to correct that.

The first IF ensures that the "list header" appears the first time - in the sample, followed by a new paragraph: everything in the "quotes" defines the True, then the False result.
The SET statement defines a bookmark - this is to enable you to track when the "list header" value changes.
The next IF creates a list entry. In the result Word document you show us, this is a table: You must define the entire table within the IF field's "True" result (inside the quotes).